# Java: Drag&Drop: get data back to main class from DropTargetDropEvent

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a main GUI [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFDHC.png) that is used to load and display (thumbnail) images.
I want to make it possible to drag&drop images on my Gui as well.
So I copied an example and put it in a class

```
    public static class FileDragDropListener implements DropTargetListener {

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent event)  {

            DragDropListener DDL = new DragDropListener();
            // Accept copy drops
            event.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
            // Get the transfer which can provide the dropped item data
            Transferable transferable = event.getTransferable();
            // Get the data formats of the dropped item
            DataFlavor[] flavors = transferable.getTransferDataFlavors();

            // Loop through the flavors
            for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
                try {
                    // If the drop items are files
                    if (flavor.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                        // Get all of the dropped files
                        List <File> files = (List) transferable.getTransferData(flavor);
                        //logger.info("length of list {}", files.size());
                        File[] imgs = new File[files.size()];
                        int counter = 0;
                        // Loop them through
                        for (File file : files) {
                            // Print out the file path
                            logger.info("File path is: {}", file.getPath());
                            imgs[ counter ] = file;
                            counter++;
                        }
                        MyVariables.setSelectedFiles(imgs);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Print out the error stack
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // Inform that the drop is complete
            event.dropComplete(true);
        }
    }
```

This drag&drop as such works fine. The code:

```
// Print out the file path
logger.info("File path is: {}", file.getPath());
```

lists a row of file paths, which I dragged upon my Gui, in the console  so drag&drop as such works fine with the files.
I use a setter/getter `MyVariables.setSelectedFiles(imgs);` to make this File[] available "everywhere".

My problem is now to get this File[] with image paths back in my Gui main class **immediately after** the drop, so I can update the left panel in my Gui. For that updating I have a method `public void LoadImages` that is used from many parts in my program, which also touches multiple Gui elements, so I can't make that one static. For that I created the setter/getter, but how do I listen in my main Gui thread for the `event.dropComplete(true);` to act on it.
I tried many things like Observers, listeners etc., but I always get the `non static method cannot be be referenced from a static context`.
I do understand that, but how do I get my Gui  notified after the drop event has finished, so that it can pick up the data using the getter?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.
The above mentioned FileDragDropListener in my first post is not necessary at all.

When I start my Gui in the `main` method, I call the below mentioned method `rootPanelDropListener`.
Note: `rootPanel` is the name of my entire main screen JPanel.
`MyVariables.setSelectedFiles(droppedFilesArray);`  is a setter I use to be able, in a later stage, to retrieve the data "everywhere" in my program.
`loadImages("dropped files");` is the method that loads the images (obvious) and has 3 options: by directory, by selecting (multiple) files, or by dropping the files onto the Gui.  Inside the `loadimages` I check on the parameter "dropped files", then using the getter for the dropped files like `files = MyVariables.getSelectedFiles();`

```
    public void rootPanelDropListener() {
        //Listen to drop events

        rootPanel.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent evt) {
                try {
                    evt.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                    List<File> droppedFiles = (List<File>)
                            evt.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                    for (File file : droppedFiles) {
                        logger.debug("File path is: {}", file.getPath());
                    }
                    File[] droppedFilesArray = (File[]) droppedFiles.toArray(new File[droppedFiles.size()]);
                    MyVariables.setSelectedFiles(droppedFilesArray);
                    loadImages("dropped files");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error("Drag drop on rootpanel error {}", ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```